Error al deployar Azure Container Instance (ACI)
Alguien con experiencia en Docker en Azure?,
Me tira error cuando hago deploy un ACI (Azure Container instance).
No importa la región que le coloque, siempre me tira el mismo error
Ya miré Usage + Quota y todo está bien allí. No me he excedido en nada.
El error es el siguiente:
Resource type 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups' container group quota 'ContainerGroups' exceeded in region 'eastus'. Limit: '0', Usage: '0' Requested: '1'. (Code: ServiceUnavailable)

Según Microsoft Learn, el error se genera por que se intenta crear varios containers a la vez. Pero no es mi caso, yo solo le estoy dando la orden de crear 1 solo container.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Hola Alex, bienvenido, tanto los códigos como los msj. de error, deben estar como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adecues a los lineamientos del sitio, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y/o que esta sea cerrada.

Allí lo edité. Muchas gracias por tu mensaje.
